# ¿Por qué no puedo instalar redis-py?

Tags: python, jupyter, redis

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install redis-py
```

después de hacer esas lineas en Jupyter Notebook, tengo el siguiente mesaje

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement redis-py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for redis-py
```

¿ cómo instalar redis in python ?, lo he intentado de mil maneras y no puedo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No encuentro el paquete `redis-py` en https://pypi.org/, solo encuentro el paquete `redis`

Comment: Tienes razón. He hecho tantas pruebas con instalar en Anaconda con pip y conda que se me paso hacerlo así en Jupyter. Desde luego con redis se instala y luego puedo importar redis, pero ¿sabes cual es la diferencia entre redis y redis-py?. ¿ Puede ser que redis-py sea para Ubuntu? ( tambien he intentado instalarlo en la maquina Ununtu de la Strore de Windows 10 y me da otros problemas). ````https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400556/in-a-windows10-computer-i-installed-ubuntu-from-store-i-try-to-run-docker-but-i````     Gracias

Comment: ¿De donde sacaste el nombre `redis-py`?

Comment: He estado toda la mañana intentando poner en marcha un entorno para una práctica de la UNED. Te lo dice en la práctica. Pero además, lo he visto en muchas páginas de ayuda. Si pones redis-py en google te saldrá un monton. La verdad es que de Python se un poco, pero de Redis es lo primero que estoy haciendo. Me lo había instalado en el ordenador directamente pero te lo pide en entorno de Jupyter y NoteBook, así que... además habian colgado una imagen de docker para el entorno, pero en Ubunto... así que he estado entretenido....

Comment: Estas confundiendo el nombre del proyecto https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py con el nombre del paquete `redis`, si revisas el readme: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#installation veras que señala que la forma de instalación es: `pip install redis`

Comment: Sólo he encontrado una única referencia que ponga `pip install redis-py`. Es posible que quien haya hecho la documentación no lo haya probado nunca (["Redis Cookbook: Practical Techniques for Fast Data Manipulation"](https://books.google.es/books?id=ZqP8E3CmWggC&lpg=PA10&ots=pCw1ouWJeO&dq=%22pip%20install%20redis-py%22%20python%20package&hl=es&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q=%22pip%20install%20redis-py%22%20python%20package&f=false) by Tiago Macedo, Fred Oliveira)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por vuestro interes y ayuda.

Al final me pude instalar los paquetes. La pregunta era para Redis, pero añado mongodb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]